# Why is there no Typescript compile error when I treat a number as an array?

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors

I'm wondering why there's no error when I do something blatantly wrong like this:

```
const test : number = 123;
const test2 = test[3];
```

This is the tsconfig I'm using:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the setting "Typescript validation" turned on?

Comment: @forensor not sure which setting that is, but it seems the "strict" flag is what I needed (see accepted answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
"strict": true
```

to your tsconfig.